# Qual a Função e Utilidade de “context” em “Widget build(BuildContext context)”

Tags: flutter

Vejo em muitos exemplos que `context` é utilizado apenas com parâmetros para outras funções. Em outros casos para pegar alguma propriedade do `widget` pai.

Afinal, qual a função e qual melhor exemplo ilustra boas práticas da utilização do `context` em `Widget build(BuildContext context)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Context` é apenas uma referência para identificar o teu Widget dentro da árvore de estrutura.

Cada `Context` pertence apenas a um Widget. Podemos entender também que, se um determinado Widget "A" possuí filhos, o `Context` do Widget "A" será o contexto pai dos seus filhos...

[image: Exemplo]

Podemos acessar essa herança através do `of`, como por exemplo:

> AlgumaCoisa.of(context)

Assim será retornado para nós essa "AlgumaCoisa" do Widget mais próximo da árvore.

Um exemplo mais prático é quando utilizamos o comando `MediaQuery.of(context).size`, que nos retorna as dimensões do nosso dispositivo, baseando-se no Widget `MaterialApp` mais próximo da árvore.

*Existe uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54480937/10145630) semelhante a sua no StackOverflow em Inglês, caso queira dar uma olhada.*

Fonte: [Widget - State - Context - InheritedWidget](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/06/widget---state---context---inheritedwidget/)

Comment: Muita resposta boa cara. Parabéns!